# Initializing an empty np.array to assign values to it

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to assign values to a multi dimensional np.array for example if H is complex of shape (3,2,4):

```
H=np.array([[[ 0. +0.j,  1. +1.j,  2. +2.j,  3. +3.j],
        [ 4. +4.j,  5. +5.j,  6. +6.j,  7. +7.j]],

       [[ 8. +8.j,  9. +9.j, 10.+10.j, 11.+11.j],
        [12.+12.j, 13.+13.j, 14.+14.j, 15.+15.j]],

       [[16.+16.j, 17.+17.j, 18.+18.j, 19.+19.j],
        [20.+20.j, 21.+21.j, 22.+22.j, 23.+23.j]]])
```

Now assume that I make a certain operations in H and then assign the new values to a new list F, so I initiate a aero np.array of complex type:

```
F  = np.zeros([3, 2, 4], dtype=complex)
for a in range(0, 3):
        for b in range(0, 2):
            for c in range(0, 4):
                F[a][b][c] = H[a][b][c]
```

the following error sometimes occurs:

TypeError: 'numpy.complex128' object does not support item assignment

and also

return np.asarray(x, float)

ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part

what is the best way to initiate an empty np.array to be assigned with complex numbers?

Comment: You've defined `F` as a 2D array, but you're dealing with it like it's a 3D array (`F[a][b][c] = ...`). If you want `F` to be the same size as `H`, define it like this: `np.zeros((3, 2, 4), dtype=complex)`

Comment: sorry it was a typo error, thanks I corrected the question

Comment: Could you share the error message and the line to which it refers? Because I run these two code snippets and it works just fine (without any errors or warnings). It's possible that the error is rising somewhere else.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just copy the original array, e.g., `F = H.copy()`, rather than trying to assign all the values individually?

Comment: Also, the NumPy [`zeros_like`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros_like.html) function is useful if you just want an array of zeros that is the same shape and type as `H`, e.g., `F = np.zeros_like(H)`.

Comment: Use `F[a, b, c]` style of array indexing.  Read more numpy basics if that's new to you.

Comment: That 'complex warning' should be obvious.  For further help show the actual code and full error message(s)

Comment: You can try to make a copy/deepcopy out of it: `F = copy.deepcopy(H)`